# UITableView height equal to contentSize height

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uitableviewautomaticdimension

I have a scroll view and inside of if couple labels and a tableView. I would like for that tableView to be scrolled by a outer scrollView and not the tableView's scrollView, so what I did is to set constraint for tableView height to be equal to contentSize height. But I have this problem that it is sized correctly only when push animation is completed (and `viewDidLayoutSubviews` gets called, I guess)

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
    tableHeightConstraint?.constant = tableViewController.tableView.contentSize.height
}
```

[Video Link](https://streamable.com/hgqpr)

Comment: use autolayout in cell and add `tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
        tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 320`

Comment: reload your tableview and after a dispatch of 0.7 second set the constraint it will work fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Content size will refresh with scroll view logic. So layout subviews is surely not enough. I have one case where I resize table view depending on it's content. What I do is use intrinsic size (it is that compression priority thing in storyboard). I subclass the table view and override these:

```
override var contentSize:CGSize {
    didSet {
        self.invalidateIntrinsicContentSize()
    }
}

override var intrinsicContentSize: CGSize {
    self.layoutIfNeeded()
    return CGSize(width: UIViewNoIntrinsicMetric, height: contentSize.height)
}
```

The rest may then be done with constraints. Im my case I do not resize it further then it's superview but you do what you must. Still a bit of caution here: If this is not restricted you destroy the table view dequeuing feature and all the cells may be loaded instantly which may consume loads of memory and CPU. I would avoid that if possible. And if not, the next best thing is using a vertical stack view on a scroll view which should produce the same result you seem to expect.

Comment: Okay, had to check a couple of times to confirm that this indeed helps! :o
Thanks, a lot!